# Prosecutorial discretion and jurisdiction

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, civil-procedure, parliamentary-procedure

## Scenario

Let's say someone wanted to force a US State to get into a legal battle to resolve an open issue that the legal system has been reluctant to resolve and for which existing laws were murky.

If a person went to a solicitor and accused an entity of illegal activity knowing in advance that the solicitor or the district attorney would try to refuse to take the case, would it theoretically be possible to then file suit against the solicitor under 42 U.S.C. 1983:

> "Every person who, under color of any statute, ordinance, regulation, custom, or usage, of any State or Territory or the District of Columbia, subjects, or causes to be subjected, any citizen of the United States or other person within the jurisdiction thereof to the deprivation of any rights, privileges, or immunities secured by the Constitution and laws, shall be liable to the party injured in an action at law, suit in equity, or other proper proceeding for redress, except that in any action brought against a judicial officer for an act or omission taken in such officer’s judicial capacity, injunctive relief shall not be granted unless a declaratory decree was violated or declaratory relief was unavailable."

#### It is assumed:

The evidence for crimes will be solid, but the context of prosecution is not.  There is no clear procedure for what court would be responsible for bringing the case to court.  This is the primary reason that a DA or solicitor would refuse the case.  Criminal court would handle the charges, but before criminal court could hear the case, damage (personal injury) would have to be established.  Civil court would handle damages, but before a damage suit can be brought a criminal liability must be established.  Procedural catch-22.

Keep in mind that the goal of this is to force a *state* to address a question when both state and federal government want the other to take care of the problem so that they don't have to deal with the fallout.

## The question:

Is there an existing governance process that exists to handle such a problem?  If there is, then this would be the correct answer. This could be a legal mechanism or a legislative mechanism.

Is there a *legal* procedure of which I am unaware? I cross-posted this into Politics.SE because I honestly don't think there is a clear area capable of resolving the question in isolation (yet).

### Narrowing Scope:

As an example of this case in a hypothetical situation.  A person has their life threatened by a mobster.  The mobster is guilty of a crime for which solid evidence exists.  A private citizen brings the evidence to a solicitor, but due to being bought off or because of political pressure or some other reason that should be determined by the court the DA refuses to prosecute.  A person in the solicitor's office tips off the mobster and the mobster kills the individual's dog, burns down his house, and does other horrible things to the individual.  The mobster is found guilty of the crimes and punished.  The individual wishes to sue the DA in civil court.  Can this be done?  Updated: I suppose for the purposes of this discussion, suit of the county might be more appropriate than suit of the DA.

## Context of the question and why it is here

- This is a procedural question having to do with political management of legal entities, not of federal, state, criminal or common law.
- This is a speculative question.  I do not expect anyone to have a firm definitive answer, but I do not rule out the possibility that one exists. I am asking here because of that choice not to rule out the possibility that an answer exists.

#### Tangential:

I found [this article](https://reason.com/archives/2008/04/24/suing-the-da) to put into better words than my own why prosecutorial immunity goes too far right now.  This doesn't bear directly on my question, but it does explain why my question is important.

Comment: All prosecutions are discretionary. No legal requirement for a prosecutor to actually decide to prosecute that specific case. 42 U.S.C. 1983 is meant to be used when a government agent deprives you of an actual right. Having them prosecute someone is not covered.

Comment: @Viktor thank you for your reply.  I do realize that prosecutions are discretionary.  I am exploring the possibility of a violation of `42 U.S.C. 1983` in which personal injury is caused by failure to prosecute in violation of the right to legal redress of grievances.  In effect, proving that liberty has been violated by refusal to enforce law to the detriment of the plaintiff.

Comment: They don't have such a duty.

Comment: Unless you can show there is no equal protection, like they enforce the law for one group of people and not another.

Comment: @Viktor now see that's a very good observation.  Let's run with that.  How would one go about showing that there is no equal protection? (in the context of the hypothetical scenario of types of legal entity as opposed to groups of people)

Comment: @Viktor actually I did a little research on this.  In this case the entity wouldn't matter because the US ammendment for equal protection extended to 'person' already has clear precedent established as being applied to all legal entities where criminal activity is established.  Thus equal protection should extend to person vs. legal entity.

Comment: Please cite specifically what you read. Also you can't show a lack of equal protection if the authority does not enforce the law at all.

Comment: The foundation of the precedent was, of course, the SC headnote in (118 U.S. 394).  However built upon that precedent is a clear chain of establishment for criminal liability of 'legal personhood', none of which apply directly but all of which establish the legal precedent that legal personhood is extended to criminal law.  I am proposing an argument that if a human being would be prosecuted for the crime, but a legal entity would not, that the rights of the human being have been violated under the 14th amendment.

Comment: any entity with personhood can be prosecuted. Typically a successful prosecutor results in fines and could potentially have the company seized by the government.

Comment: Excellent.  So I *may* have a case if the DA refuses to prosecute for any reason other than lack of evidence?  (note the stress of *may*.  How the case is refused will, of course, matter).

Comment: @SkyLeach Almost certainly not. Prosecutors can decline to prosecute for many reasons, including "the interests of justice would not be served." In fact, they have a *duty* to use their discretion to seek justice rather than seek convictions wherever possible.

Comment: @cpast while this does indeed appear to protect prosecutors, it also appears to be a loophole for counties to work around the 14th amendment.  Thus I believe you are correct, but I think there may be a real case for suing the county itself under these conditions.

Comment: @SkyLeach Your question is really too general -- you keep talking about "these circumstances," but it's unclear what exactly you mean. What law would you seek to have enforced? If you have a specific example in mind and we're guessing, it doesn't really work.

Comment: No. They have qualified immunity and no duty to prosecute. Just because you believe they have evidence doesn't meant that they have enough evidence to prosecute. If you had proof of bribery, you wouldn't bring suit; the government would under anti-racketeering laws. Section 1983 is reserved for when a gov't actor commits a criminal act under color of law, ie. they use their position to commit a crime against you personally. It is not enough to say you suffered a remote injury.

Comment: @cpast I have been trying to narrow the focus a bit, but your feedback about that is greatly appreciated

Comment: @gracey209 - I fully realize that they have 'qualified immunity'.  I also realize that they have no legal obligation to give `cause of action` in refusal to prosecute.  Therein is a key part of the argument.  I know that most DAs, my home state's NCDOJ specifically, dismisses out-of-hand charges of criminal conduct brought by non-government institutions against corporate/business entities regardless of evidence submitted unless they are sole-proprietorships.  They aren't even considered _at all_.  I consider this to be unjust, and I'm asking if it is arguably illegal.

Comment: Reading this I expected it to be a question about the Bill Cosby rape prosecution in Montgomery county PA. DA Castor decided against prosecution in 2005. DA Steele was just elected (with a vague promise to review - too bad for Cosby he was front page news in November), and is now prosecuting within the statute of limitations. The system works since it was implied to be part of the election?

Comment: @user662852 I would argue that in the cosby case the fact that an election was required reinforces my argument.  Imagine what our law would be like if every criminal case required popular public support before it was pursued!?  And this is about a `class of criminal` in the rich and famous.  How do you make anything like that work for non-human entities?

Comment: @gracey209 Actually, prosecutors have absolute immunity from 1983 actions and not just qualified immunity for their charging decisions (they have qualified immunity when involved in pre-prosecution investigatory activities).

Comment: The person providing the tip might be subject to a civil action individually (probably not under 1983) for civil conspiracy to commit a tort, because prosecutorial immunity generally does not extend to collaborating with a criminal and foreseeably injuring someone without official sanction to do so from the DA, and might also be subject to criminal prosecution along the lines of abuse of official office. But, not the DA who simply decided not to prosecute.

Answer (score 2):

[Private prosecution of crimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_prosecution#United_States) has become increasingly uncommon under common law systems, which have [increased deference to public prosecutors](http://law.jrank.org/pages/1855/Prosecution-Comparative-Aspects-decision-prosecute.html).

The U.S. Supreme Court eliminated private prosecution at the federal level in *[Leeke v. Timmerman](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/454/83/case.html)*, (1981), 452 U.S. 83.  The closest exception found in case law appears to be an allowance for a federal court to appoint a private attorney to prosecute a criminal contempt action if the executive refuses to prosecute.  (*[Young v. U.S. ex rel. Vuitton et Fils](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/481/787/)*, (1987)
481 U.S. 787.)

At least some U.S. states allow "[Private Challenges to Prosecutorial Inaction](http://www.jstor.org/stable/796415)."  These [can take different forms](http://isthatlegal.org/private-prosecution/):

> Some states do allow a complainant to either file a request for an
>   order to show cause or to actually prosecute as a private prosecutor.

For example, in Pennsylvania, private criminal complaints are forwarded to a public prosecutor.  If the public attorney declines to prosecute then [the complainant can request a judicial review of that decision](http://www.pacode.com/secure/data/234/chapter5/s506.html).  The standard of review almost always requires the petitioner to show that the failure to prosecute was "[an abuse of prosecutorial discretion](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/2403806/in-re-wilson/)."  And I can't find any such case in which the complainant prevailed, so it's not certain what the remedy would be in that event.  (Our best guess is that the private complainant would be allowed to prosecute the case.)

[Wisconsin](http://scholarship.law.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1813&context=mulr) provides a similar [statutory mechanism for judicial review of prosecutorial inaction](http://law.justia.com/codes/wisconsin/2012/chapter-968/section-968.02).  [This good Law Review article](http://scholarship.law.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1813&context=mulr) explains the Wisconsin law.

[This 2004 Law Review article](http://suffolklawreview.org/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/McCormack.pdf) compares New Hampshire (which does have mechanisms for private prosecution) with Massachusetts (which does not).

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal duty on any state to pursue criminal prosecution. The legal duty extends only to giving consideration to doing so. If, **after consideration**, they decide not to, then no one can force them to. Case law on this is limited to the court ordering *consideration* when none was given.

Comment: I can't agree.  There is legal duty provided by the 14th amendment.  If a state only pursues prosecution of cases which are affordable, or which are easy (in terms of time and/or staff) then they are effectively neglecting their obligations under federal law.  In addition it can be argued that in many cases failure to prosecute can be considered a violation of state law under state constitutions.

Comment: Dale: AFAIK this isn't entirely accurate.  Courts can not only order prosecutors to consider a case, but they can also find an "abuse of prosecutorial discretion" and then decide themselves whether the state has to prosecute a case, enforce a law, etc.

Comment: @feetwet could you cite some case law on this subject? Plus prosecutors cannot ethically pursue a case that they don't believe beyond a reasonable doubt...

Comment: @Viktor - Your question and observation really merit more research ... which I haven't had time to perform.  "[Abuse of discretion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutorial_misconduct#Abuses_of_discretion)" usually takes other forms.  But I suspect that, if nothing else, there must be examples of courts ruling that a prosecutor has abused his discretion for failing to enforce desegregation laws in the U.S. civil rights era.  I wonder what the remedies are.  Perhaps this merits its own question.

Comment: @Viktor - The most recent reference I could find is from a 1988 *Yale Law Journal* article, "[Private Challenges to Prosecutorial Inaction](http://www.jstor.org/stable/796415)."  It notes that (at the time) at least 9 states had statutory schemes that potentially enable private persons to challenge prosecutorial inaction.  But apparently there was no case law indicating what redress should be expected.